# using transform:translate method in @media only screen rule

Tags: hover, media

I try to using transform:translate method for hover effect in @media only screen  rule, but it doesn't work.
Without **@media** rule, hove method is OK with mouseower.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried to use? The code that works, and the code that doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

/* Here is css code */

```
.cs-hover a.info { 
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 350px);  
-moz-transform: translate(0px, 350px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, 350px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 350px);`
transform: translate(0px, 350px);
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.cs-hover:hover a.info {
-webkit-transform: translate(60px,25px); 
-moz-transform: translate(60px,25px);
-o-transform: translate(60px,25px);
-ms-transform: translate(60px,25px);
transform: translate(60px,25px); 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
transition-delay: 0.2s;}
}
```

Comment: This is code that no work hoved method. If I remove @media {} rule in CSS code is everything OK.